# date check to avoid exception in sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a query, where I need to apply the TO_DATE(format specified is 'DD.MM.YYYY') function to a VARCHAR type column. However, it is possible that the date may be invalid
e.g. 'aa.12.2012' or '31.02.2012'  etc

This will lead to and exception when TO_DATE function processes the faulty date value and the query will fail.

One way to do it is to run cursor and identify every cell with faulty date, but I want to avoid this way.

I tried to work with regular expression, but was I did not succeed to place all validations.

It was like this

```
select
 case
   when regexp_like('24.01.2013',
                    '[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]]{4}') then
    1
   else
    0
 end chk
  from dual
```

This was not able to catch invalid dates like 31st of Feb.

Is it possible to do all validation in the regular expression for date, because I performed all validations via decode & case and it is rather lengthy.

```
SELECT DECODE((REPLACE(TRANSLATE('29.01.2013', '0123456789.', ' '), ' ', '')),
              NULL,
              (CASE
                WHEN LENGTH('29.01.2013') != 10 THEN
                 'FALSE'
                WHEN LENGTH('29.01.2013') -
                     LENGTH(REPLACE(TRANSLATE('29.01.2013', '.', ' '),
                                    ' ',
                                    '')) != 2 THEN
                 'FALSE'
                WHEN INSTR('29.01.2013', '.', 1, 1) != 3 THEN
                 'FALSE'
                WHEN INSTR('29.01.2013', '.', 1, 2) != 6 THEN
                 'FALSE'
                WHEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 4, 2)) IN
                     (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) THEN
                 (CASE
                WHEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 1, 2)) >= 1 AND
                     TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 1, 2)) <= 31 THEN
                 'TRUE'
                ELSE
                 'FALSE'
              END) WHEN
              TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 4, 2)) IN (4, 6, 9, 11)
              THEN(CASE
                     WHEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 1, 2)) >= 1 AND
                          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 1, 2)) <= 30 THEN
                      'TRUE'
                     ELSE
                      'FALSE'
                   END) WHEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 4, 2)) IN (2)
              THEN(CASE
                     WHEN REMAINDER(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 7, 4)), 4) = 0 THEN
                      (CASE
                     WHEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 1, 2)) >= 1 AND
                          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 1, 2)) <= 29 THEN
                      'TRUE'
                     ELSE
                      'FALSE'
                   END) WHEN
              REMAINDER(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 7, 4)), 4) != 0
              THEN(CASE
                     WHEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 1, 2)) >= 1 AND
                          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('29.01.2013', 1, 2)) <= 28 THEN
                      'TRUE'
                     ELSE
                      'FALSE'
                   END) END) END), 'FALSE')
  FROM DUAL
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you store a `DATE` in a `VARCHAR` column in the first place. If you use the correct data type then you wouldn't need such a kludge

Comment: Fair point, however I dump the values from an excel(without check) into this field. I need to accurately identify and report in case date format error exits, otherwise the valid date is to be utilised

Answer (score 0):

The following regex validates date:

```
^(((?=\d{2}\.(0[13578]|1[02]))(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|((?=\d{2}\.(0[469]|11))(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30))|((?=\d{2}\.02\.\d{2}([02468][048]|[13579][26]))(0[1-9]|[12]\d))|(((?=\d{2}\.02\.\d{2}([02468][^048]|[13579][^26]))(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))))\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(0{3}[1-9]|((?!0{3}\d)\d{4}))$
```

**Note:** There will be a simpler regex using conditional expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I can never fully get regular expressions to work in cases like this -- 99% of the time they can, but things like leap year are always a difficult one.

I have seen this online before that seems to work well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY2DATE (p_str IN VARCHAR2
  ,format_picture IN VARCHAR2
)
   RETURN DATE
IS
BEGIN
   RETURN TO_DATE(p_str, format_picture);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

Basically, pass the string value and the format, and it will return NULL if any exceptions are caught.

Good luck.

Comment: I already did that, but I want that will require a procedure. I want to write a query that avoids invalid dates. Something like IS NULL, which successfully avoids NULL value rows. I just want the same for avoiding invalid date